# Nested class's raw pointer class member fails to return assigned pointed-to-object's data

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a holder class `H` with a `unique_ptr` to an instance of class `A` (`H` is the owner of `A`). Class `A` defines a nested class `B`, and has a `unique_ptr` to an instance of `B` (`A` is the owner of `B`). In turn, `A`'s instance of `B` should update aspects of its `A`, and therefore `B` has a raw pointer to the `A` that owns it.

My problem is that when members of A are updated, B cannot return them accurately. When B is being created, and its pointer to its owning A is created, its pointer is going out of scope.

I can get this to work when the holder class is not present (i.e. A is not owned by anyone, but is still pointed to by its instance of B).

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// define class A
class A{



public:
  A(int x, int y);

  // define class B within A
  class B {
  public:
    B(A& a, int y);

  private:
    int b_y;
    A* b_a;

  public:
    void update_B(){
      std::cout << "Updating y of B belonging to A with x value " << b_a->a_x << std::endl;
      b_y += 1;
    }
  }; // end of class B

private:
  int a_x;
  std::unique_ptr<B> a_b;

public:
  void update_A(){
    std::cout << "Updating A...";
    a_x += 1;
    std::cout << " A's x is now " << a_x << std::endl;
    a_b->update_B();
  }
}; // end of class A


// define class H
class H{
public:
  H(int x, int y);
private:
  std::unique_ptr<A> h_a;

public:
  void update_h(){
    h_a->update_A();
  }
}; // end of class H

// define class A's constructor
A::A(int x, int y) {
  std::cout << "...creating instance of A... " << std::endl;
  a_x = x;
  a_b = std::make_unique<B> (B(*this, y)); // assign the unique ptr to B
  std::cout << "...A's x is set to " << x << std::endl;
}


// define class B's constructor
A::B::B(A& a, int y) {
  std::cout << ":- Creating instance of B within A..." << std::endl;
  b_a = &a; // assign B's pointer to the A instance that called it
  b_y = y;
  std::cout << ":- ...B's y is set to " << b_y << std::endl;
  std::cout << ":- ...B belongs to an A with value " << b_a->a_x << std::endl;
}


// define class H's constructor
H::H(int x, int y){
  std::cout << "Creating instance of H" << std::endl;
  h_a = std::make_unique<A> (A(x, y)); // assign the unique ptr to A
}


// main function
int main()
{
  // create instance of H
  H h(2, 10);
  // update the H function, which calls update_A and update_y
  h.update_h();
  return 0;
}
```

The expected result is:

```
Creating instance of H
...creating instance of A... 
:- Creating instance of B within A...
:- ...B's y is set to 10
:- ...B belongs to an A with value 2
...A's x is set to 2
Updating A... A's x is now 3
Updating y of B belonging to A with x value 3
```

but the actual result is:

```
Creating instance of H
...creating instance of A... 
:- Creating instance of B within A...
:- ...B's y is set to 10
:- ...B belongs to an A with value 2
...A's x is set to 2
Updating A... A's x is now 3
Updating y of B belonging to A with x value <some massive number>
```

It seems that B is not tracking the A instance it originally pointed to.

I can get the code to work by explicitly passing `*this` to `B`'s `update_B()` function, like `update_B(A& a){ b_a = &a; }` but I don't understand why the above doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for any insight you have.

Comment: (BTW, I assume you meant "`B` ... has a raw pointer to the `A` that *owns it*"?)

Comment: @Matthew Yes, thank you. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being bitten by the implicit move constructor of `A`. The problem is this line:

```cpp
h_a = std::make_unique<A> (A(x, y));
```

This constructs an unique pointer to an `A` from the given argument(s), `A(x, y)`. IOW, you are constructing an `A` from *an already constructed* instance of an `A`. This second instance is move-constructed from the first, and so takes over the first's instance of `B`, which now has a wrong pointer to its owning instance.

You can see this if you modify your code to print the identities of `A` and `B` as you are doing things to them:

```
Creating instance of H
...creating instance of A (0x7ffecd5a6d40)... 
:- Creating instance of B (0x7ffecd5a6cf0) within A (0x7ffecd5a6d40)...
:- ...B's y is set to 10
:- ...B belongs to an A with value 2
...A's x is set to 2
Updating A (0x19852a0)... A's x is now 3
Updating y of B (0x1985280) belonging to A (0x7ffecd5a6d40) with x value -849711776
```

If I change your code to:

```cpp
h_a = std::make_unique<A>(x, y);
```

...then it works as expected:

```
Creating instance of H
...creating instance of A (0x877280)... 
:- Creating instance of B (0x7ffe479156c0) within A (0x877280)...
:- ...B's y is set to 10
:- ...B belongs to an A with value 2
...A's x is set to 2
Updating A (0x877280)... A's x is now 3
Updating y of B (0x8772a0) belonging to A (0x877280) with x value 3
```

However, this is not the full solution. What you really need to do is either provide a move constructor for `A` that updates the owned instance of `B` to have the correct pointer, or at least explicitly delete the move constructor so that you can't accidentally misuse the class.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually been misunderstanding the use of make_unique<class>. Your part solution is actually what I should have been writing.